# DJI M210 ，can not alloca bandwidth

Tags: dji-sdk

I am using Mobile SDK to develop a M210 special  app。 
When I try to alloc aircraft bandwidth using the following code ：

```
 DJIAirLink * airlink= [DemoComponentHelper fetchAirLink];
[airlink.lightbridgeLink setBandwidthAllocationForMainCamera:1.0 withCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if(error){
            NSLog(@"%@",error);}];
 [ airlink.lightbridgeLink setBandwidthAllocationForLeftCamera:0.7 withCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
                if(error){
                    NSLog(@"%@",error);
                }];
```

I get a error:Current product does not support this feature.(code:-1013)

Can anybody explain this error ？ thanks

Comment: I've been getting the same error from `getBandwidthAllocationForLeftCamera()`, although I'm using Swift. I haven't been able to figure this out either - were you ever able to make your code work?